CSS - How to place content between my column borders
I think this question is better suited for a "show" don't tell. So I'll start off with a screenshot of my current design:

I want the times to show between the columns header, is that even possible? I wish do to it statically right now, I have 16 columns. Technically I have 17, but I want the time to appear from the first column line to the last, so like this:

And if there is a way to make the column borders extend to the top a bit, that would be nice too!
Here's my code in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zqu3n1jw/1/
Here's the code:
<template>
    <div class="calendar">
        <!-- Header -->
      <div class="calendar__header">
            <div class="calendar__header--time">6:00</div>
            <div class="calendar__header--time">7:00</div>
            <div class="calendar__header--time">8:00</div>
            <div class="calendar__header--time">9:00</div>
            <div class="calendar__header--time">10:00</div>
            <div class="calendar__header--time">11:00</div>
            <div class="calendar__header--time">12:00</div>
            <div class="calendar__header--time">13:00</div>
            <div class="calendar__header--time">14:00</div>
            <div class="calendar__header--time">15:00</div>
            <div class="calendar__header--time">16:00</div>
            <div class="calendar__header--time">17:00</div>
            <div class="calendar__header--time">18:00</div>
            <div class="calendar__header--time">19:00</div>
            <div class="calendar__header--time">20:00</div>
            <div class="calendar__header--time">21:00</div>
            <div class="calendar__header--time">22:00</div>
        </div>
        <!-- Body -->
        <div class="calendar__body">
            <div class="calendar__row" v-for="(activity, index) in activities" :key="index">
                <div class="calendar__cell">{{ activity.name }}</div>
                <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
                <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
                <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
                <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
                <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
                <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
                <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
                <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
                <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
                <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
                <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
                <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
                <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
                <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
                <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
                <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <div class="calendar__footer">
            <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">TOTAL</span></div>
            <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
            <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
            <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
            <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
            <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
            <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
            <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
            <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
            <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
            <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
            <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
            <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
            <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
            <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
            <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
            <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<style scoped lang="scss" src="./Calendar.scss"></style>
<script lang="ts" src="./Calendar.ts"></script>


Use text-align:center; and translateX(-50%);.
Set .calendar__header--time same width as .calendar__cell.
Add flex-shrink: 0; on .calendar__header--time:first-child and .calendar__cell:first-child to prevent first col become smaller than 16%.
.calendar__header--time {
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: lightblue;
  width: 6%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.calendar__header--time:first-child {
  width: 16%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.calendar__cell:first-child {
  width: 16%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  justify-content: left;
  padding: 0;
}



const {
  createApp
} = Vue;

createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      activities: [{
          name: "Planning"
        },
        {
          name: "Replenishment"
        },
        {
          name: "Picking"
        },
        {
          name: "Packing"
        },
        {
          name: "Shipping"
        },
        {
          name: "Problem solving"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}).mount('#app');
.calendar {
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.calendar__row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed gray;
}

.calendar__header {
  display: flex;
}

.calendar__header--time {
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: lightblue;
  width: 6%;
  transform: translateX(50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.calendar__cell {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-grow: 0;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  width: 6%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 50px;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

.calendar__footer {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #E8E9EB;
}

.calendar__header--time:first-child {
  width: 16%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.calendar__cell:first-child {
  width: 16%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  justify-content: left;
  padding: 0;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="calendar">
  <!-- Header -->
  <div class="calendar__header">
    <div class="calendar__header--time">6:00</div>
    <div class="calendar__header--time">7:00</div>
    <div class="calendar__header--time">8:00</div>
    <div class="calendar__header--time">9:00</div>
    <div class="calendar__header--time">10:00</div>
    <div class="calendar__header--time">11:00</div>
    <div class="calendar__header--time">12:00</div>
    <div class="calendar__header--time">13:00</div>
    <div class="calendar__header--time">14:00</div>
    <div class="calendar__header--time">15:00</div>
    <div class="calendar__header--time">16:00</div>
    <div class="calendar__header--time">17:00</div>
    <div class="calendar__header--time">18:00</div>
    <div class="calendar__header--time">19:00</div>
    <div class="calendar__header--time">20:00</div>
    <div class="calendar__header--time">21:00</div>
    <div class="calendar__header--time">22:00</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Body -->
  <div class="calendar__body">
    <div class="calendar__row" v-for="(activity, index) in activities" :key="index">
      <div class="calendar__cell">{{ activity.name }}</div>
      <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
      <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
      <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
      <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
      <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
      <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
      <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
      <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
      <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
      <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
      <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
      <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
      <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
      <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
      <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
      <div class="calendar__cell"><span class="calendar__cell--value">Cool</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="calendar__footer">
    <!-- Footer content here -->
  </div>
</div>




Actually it doesn't really work because the first column is bigger than the rest, i forgot to add
  &__cell:nth-child(17n + 1) {
    width: 16%;
    justify-content: left;
    padding: 0;
  }

In my css

I updated my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a4ukys2p/ . Sorry about that!

Why not use :first-child?

Chatgpt told me to use nthchild, first-child is better?

If you only need to make first col wider, yes.

ok thank you! and how can my initial question work when the first column is wider. What do i need to change in your answer?

I had updated my answer.

Doesn't seem to work for me :/

I dont want the time to appear at the start of the header only on the second column

If the time is start from 6:00, add transform: translateX(50%); on .calendar__header--time.

Based on what you are trying to achieve, I would rather use a table which will handle most of the layout for you.
Adding just a translate 50% on the header will give you the expected rendering:


th {
  translate: 50%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid rgb(160 160 160);
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>6:00</th>
      <th>7:00</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>planning</td>
    <td>cool</td>
    <td>cool</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>problem solving</td>
    <td>cool</td>
    <td>cool</td>
  </tr>
</table>



